# ElasticSearch handling for max shard size

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I learnt that, an ES Shard is nothing but a lucene index and that [Max items in Lucene Index](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-max-number-of-documents-for-one-index/26578) can be INT.MAX -128 (Approx 2Billion), but I could not find anywhere on ES reference how is this scenario handled? Does ES fail or assign another shard to documents with same `route`?

or is it something that we need to plan in advance, while designing the indexing strategies?

Comment: You need to account for this while designing your index structure and provision enough shards per index depending on how many documents you expect to store in your index.

Comment: Since I deal with Elasticsearch for > 2years now, I have never seen that limit being hit. You will have other issues with your indices that have shards with 2 billion documents until you hit that problem.